# Inserting an integer into QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

I am trying to read a binary data file using QDataStream and QByteArray, make some changes, and save off as a new file.

I have the following:

```
QDataStream in_datastream(&file);
QByteArray fileByteArray = file.readAll();
//find my insertion point
int pos = fileByteArray.indexOf(magic_num, 0);

//move to insertion point, minus 4 bytes (size of an integer)
file.seek(pos-4);
int current_val;
//check what the value is here
in_datastream >> current_val;

//now, I want to replace that value..but how?
```

I have tried several things at this point, but can't seem to figure out how to make it work. I want to insert the integer 5000 at (pos-4) in the QByteArray.

```
//remove 4 bytes..this seems to work
fileByteArray.remove(pos-4, 4);
//actually inserts garbage.
fileByteArray.insert(pos-4, newInteger);
```

If I try to insert a 4 character string "TEST", they all get inserted properly. I think I am having some type conversion problems trying to put an integer in there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, integer may have size not only 4, but 8 bytes, so you should use `sizeof(integer)` instead of 4. Then you can convert integer to string with `Qstring::number(newInteger)`. QString can be converted to bytearray with `QString::toLatin1()`

Comment: Please be aware that the "byte order" of the interger can be different on multiple devices. As long as you only use the file on the device you have created, it's ok, but if you exchange files, use [QtEndian](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtendian.html) to convert to either of the two byteorders

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will give it a try and update/accept once I have had the chance.